# 14.04 fresh install keyboard and mouse not working on reboot

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu, and my USB keyboard and mouse aren't working. I'm essentially stuck on the log-in screen with nowhere to go.

I tried rebooting and starting in recovery mode, but I can't hold shift to get into grub and choose recover mode.

I can't enter any commands, because I can't use the keyboard.

The only thing I can do is reboot and load from the Live USB. When I'm running off the Live USB, everything works fine. I've installed three times, downloaded new iso, re-made a usb with that new iso, and re-installed. Same exact issue on the login screen.

Comment: Anything special about the keyboard / mouse that we should know about? Can you borrow someone else's for a test? What's the exact make / model of the devices in question? Check your BIOS for settings that might be pertinent.

Comment: It's a Logitech Wireless Desktop MK710 mouse and keyboard combo. I checked my BIOS, and nothing pertinent here. I ensured that Legacy mode was active. I can't really borrow someone else's keyboard for a test, unfortunately.

Comment: Logitech is infamous for it's poor (read: non-existent) Linux support. ...Still if it works during install then it should be possible to make it work. If you have another machine available, one trick you can use is to install the sshd server and SSH into the box from a different box. That will get you access to the system while it is running so that you can figure out what is wrong with it. Of course that means you need a laptop or something with an SSH client.

Comment: Hmmm... some other ideas. Have you tried: lsusb -v | less to see what USB drivers get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... some other ideas. drop to the command line during a rescue boot. Make sure you are root or can sudo to get admin privileges. Use chroot so that you can change your path perspective. Makes it appear to the system that you booted normally so that you can use the system as if you hadn't booted in using a rescue stick.  Source your user profile if you have to. Next you need to check the difference between what is installed and what has been loaded into memory but not installed.

```
lsusb -v | less
```

Use the above command to review what USB devices are actually loaded. Remember the USB devices we are looking for were loaded but they are probably not installed onto your drive because they were on the stick you booted with.

K, if you can figure out the device or devices, the next trick is to figure out what package they belong to and install it. To some degree, you may be on your own in this regards as what you are looking for is a clue that I can't find for you. Here is what my keyboard device info looks like. Note the term "Human Interface Device". That usually indicates a keyboard or mouse. Also, I know the company that makes it is ROCCAT.  Also note the ID which is 1e7d:3264 Your ID is probably what you can use to track the package down which contains the drivers you need. :

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1e7d:3264 ROCCAT Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 2.00
  bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass 0
  bDeviceProtocol 0
  bMaxPacketSize0 64
  idVendor 0x1e7d ROCCAT
  idProduct 0x3264
  bcdDevice 1.00
  iManufacturer 1
  iProduct 2
  iSerial 0
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 59
    bNumInterfaces 2
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass 1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol 1 Keyboard
      iInterface 0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength 9
          bDescriptorType 33
          bcdHID 1.11
          bCountryCode 0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors 1
          bDescriptorType 34 Report
          wDescriptorLength 65
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0040 1x 64 bytes
        bInterval 1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 1
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass 0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol 0 None
      iInterface 0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength 9
          bDescriptorType 33
          bcdHID 1.11
          bCountryCode 0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors 1
          bDescriptorType 34 Report
          wDescriptorLength 309
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x84 EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0040 1x 64 bytes
        bInterval 1
```

Comment: He doesn't have a keyboard???

Comment: Read again. Said he has a keyboard but not during a regular boot. Only when he is using an install disk. It seems logical that his drivers are not loading. Hmmm... wonder if he tried a different USB port after boot?

Comment: Correct! Your system will work!  My apologies!